# How to limit the number of ajax POST requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am using angular (in case it matters) and am trying to limit the number of ajax POST requests that my browser makes using javascript - ideally vanilla javascript on `xmlHttpRequest` object. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

To be more precise, suppose I click a button which typically triggers 15 concurrent POST requests - one for each say, "record". I would like to limit these concurrent requests to be 5 at max. Is there a low level (i.e. javascript `xmlHttpRequest`) to limit the number of these requests? It is also safe to assume the using is always going to be using either chrome or safari as this is an internal tool.

Comment: We need more information than this. How are you calling the AJAX? Is it in a loop? Is it when a user does something? Is it when the page loads? Is it in an interval or time function that runs (say) once every second? What kind of code have you tried? Can you post it so we can look at what you've tried and come up with solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That being said, if you're counting them overall, create an input: `<input id='ajaxCounter' type='hidden' value='0'/>` and then every time you call an AJAX function, add one to its value: `var el = document.getElementById('ajaxCounter'); el.value = el.value+1;`, and then in every function that calls AJAX put the AJAX function in an if function that checks the value of `ajaxCounter` against the max number of AJAX calls you want

Comment: @ctwheels there'd be no need for a hidden element, window.object.count would do

Comment: @ToniLeigh Even better!

Comment: Thanks guys. I would like to avoid any hidden elements. Please take a look at the edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use interceptors to accomplish this, catching all requests, checking if they're post methods, and stopping the request if some count has been exceeded using configs timeout property.

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    var countTimes = 0;
    var stopRequest = $q.defer();
    stopRequest.resolve();
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            if(config.method == 'POST' && countTimes < someMaxNumber) {
                countTimes += 1;
                return config;
            } else {
                config.timeout = stopRequest.promise;
                return config;
        }
    }
});
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Miles P. I need a solution such that if say 15 requests are fired, I would like to only have 5 of those executing concurrently and the rest to resume once the 5 has been resolved - 5 requests at a time. Would your solution account for this?